# SQL Join with unique rows

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two tables 
Table1

```
 - EMPLID XX_EMPLID GTN   DEDCD    EFFDT
     1     A1        102   XXYY     02-OCT-16
     1     A1        103   XXYZ     02-OCT-16
```

Table2

```
  - EMPLID  DEDCD    EFFDT
     1       XXYA     02-OCT-16
     1       XXYZ     02-OCT-16
```

When I join the select should return only two rows and the output should be

```
 - EMPLID   2.DEDCD    EFFDT        1.DEDCD
     1       XXYA     02-OCT-16      XXYY
     1       XXYZ     02-OCT-16      XXYZ
```

EMPLID,EFFDT being the key. I do not have want to join DEDCD as I need to the see the difference if any. Please suggest.

Simple join will give me more rows always. I am looking to limit the row to the number of rows in Table1. I tried "Right outer join" and "left outer join" but does not work

After some help, I am able to get close to the results. However, one issue that I am facing is pointed out below

```
10008536    XXYZ    06-MAR-02   (XXYY)  06-MAR-02
10008536    (XXYY)  06-MAR-02   XXZZ    06-MAR-02
```

**Edit 3**

Although I managed to solve my previous problem, I am facing yet another similar problem.

two tables with key structure as 
EMPLID,EMPL_RCD, BALANCE_ID, BALANCE_YEAR, BALANCE_QTR,BALANCE_PERIOD,ERNCD

I wrote a query to fetch the value from both tables using the SQL Below:

```
SELECT EBPS.EMPLID ,EBPS.BALANCE_ID ,EBPS.BALANCE_YEAR ,EBPS.BALANCE_QTR ,EBPS.BALANCE_PERIOD ,
EBPS.ERNCD ,EBCS.EMPLID ,EBCS.BALANCE_ID ,EBCS.BALANCE_YEAR ,EBCS.BALANCE_QTR ,
EBCS.BALANCE_PERIOD ,EBCS.ERNCD   
FROM 
    (
  select  EBCS1.EMPLID ,EBCS1.COMPANY ,EBCS1.BALANCE_ID ,EBCS1.BALANCE_YEAR ,EBCS1.BALANCE_QTR ,
EBCS1.BALANCE_PERIOD ,EBCS1.EMPL_RCD ,EBCS1.SPCL_BALANCE ,EBCS1.ERNCD ,EBCS1.HRS_YTD ,EBCS1.HRS_QTD ,EBCS1.HRS_MTD ,
EBCS1.GRS_YTD ,EBCS1.GRS_QTD ,EBCS1.GRS_MTD ,EBCS1.XX_EMPLOYEE_ID,
         row_number() over (partition by EBCS1.EMPLID,EBCS1.EMPL_RCD order by case when EBPS1.EMPLID is not null then 0 else 1 end asc,
         EBCS1.BALANCE_YEAR,EBCS1.BALANCE_QTR,EBCS1.BALANCE_PERIOD,EBCS1.ERNCD ) rn
  from TABLE1 EBCS1 left join 
  (select distinct EMPLID,EMPL_RCD, COMPANY, BALANCE_ID,BALANCE_YEAR,BALANCE_QTR,BALANCE_PERIOD,ERNCD,SPCL_BALANCE from TABLE2) EBPS1 on 
  EBCS1.EMPLID=EBPS1.EMPLID AND EBCS1.BALANCE_ID=EBPS1.BALANCE_ID  and EBCS1.COMPANY=EBPS1.COMPANY AND EBCS1.ERNCD=EBPS1.ERNCD
  and EBCS1.BALANCE_PERIOD = EBPS1.BALANCE_PERIOD
AND EBCS1.BALANCE_QTR = EBPS1.BALANCE_QTR AND EBCS1.EMPL_RCD = EBPS1.EMPL_RCD AND EBCS1.BALANCE_YEAR = EBPS1.BALANCE_YEAR 
AND EBCS1.SPCL_BALANCE =EBPS1.SPCL_BALANCE  ) EBCS
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     (
    select  EBPS1.EMPLID ,EBPS1.COMPANY ,EBPS1.BALANCE_ID ,EBPS1.BALANCE_YEAR ,EBPS1.BALANCE_QTR ,
EBPS1.BALANCE_PERIOD ,EBPS1.EMPL_RCD ,EBPS1.SPCL_BALANCE ,EBPS1.ERNCD ,EBPS1.HRS_YTD ,EBPS1.HRS_QTD ,EBPS1.HRS_MTD ,
EBPS1.GRS_YTD ,EBPS1.GRS_QTD ,EBPS1.GRS_MTD,
         row_number() over (partition by EBPS1.EMPLID,EBPS1.EMPL_RCD order by case when EBCS1.EMPLID is not null then 0 else 1 end asc,
         EBCS1.BALANCE_YEAR,EBCS1.BALANCE_QTR,EBCS1.BALANCE_PERIOD,EBCS1.ERNCD) rn
  from TABLE2 EBPS1  left join (select distinct EMPLID,EMPL_RCD,COMPANY,BALANCE_ID,BALANCE_YEAR,BALANCE_PERIOD,ERNCD,SPCL_BALANCE,BALANCE_QTR
  from TABLE1) EBCS1 ON
  EBCS1.EMPLID=EBPS1.EMPLID AND EBCS1.BALANCE_ID=EBPS1.BALANCE_ID  and EBCS1.COMPANY=EBPS1.COMPANY AND EBCS1.ERNCD=EBPS1.ERNCD and EBCS1.BALANCE_PERIOD = EBPS1.BALANCE_PERIOD
AND EBCS1.BALANCE_QTR = EBPS1.BALANCE_QTR AND EBCS1.EMPL_RCD = EBPS1.EMPL_RCD AND EBCS1.BALANCE_YEAR = EBPS1.BALANCE_YEAR AND EBCS1.SPCL_BALANCE =EBPS1.SPCL_BALANCE  ) EBPS
  ON ( EBPS.EMPLID=EBCS.EMPLID AND EBCS.EMPL_RCD=EBPS.EMPL_RCD   AND  EBCS.rn=EBPS.rn  )
```

However, if a row is missing from table Table2 , I get incorrect result. For example if an employee has 16 rows in Table 1 and 15 in table 2 , and for some rows the ERNCD matches but Period/Quarter does not, in that case I would like to display data with unmatched Period/Quarter but matching ERNCD. But at present the rows get unorganized if a mismatch occurs. Please let me know if anyone can figure this issue out. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: As you mentioned  `JOIN` is the answer try writing one and tell if you face any problem

Comment: What determines that the XXYA row in table2 matches to the XXYY row in table1? Why not XXYZ? Also, what is the primary key of table1?

Comment: As @Boneist already asked, you need to clarify the criteria that filter out XXYZ in the first table. Maybe you need the record for EMPLID with the greatest GTN?

Comment: The issue is the KEYS on table1 and table2 are different. Hence facing this issue

Comment: @R_Prasad if they have different keys,  please tell us the keys of both the tables.  But anyway,  can you describe in natural language what's the output you need? It seems to be that,  unless you add a condition,  there's no clear way to answer your question.

Comment: Ok, Not sure why it was marked as negative. I will paste the solution here.

Comment: I've created a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e57d1c/1) to test one of the proposed solutions. Feel free to copy it and add it to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's see if this answer suits your request.

```
SELECT a.EMPLID,a.DEDCD, to_char(a.EFFDT,'YYYY-MM-DD') EFFDT, b.DEDCD as DEDCD2,GTN 
   FROM 
   (
   select  EFFDT,GTN,EMPLID,DEDCD,
        row_number() over (partition by EMPLID order by DEDCD) rn
 from table1 ) A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
   select  EFFDT,EMPLID,DEDCD,
        row_number() over (partition by EMPLID order by DEDCD) rn
 from table2       
    ) B
 ON ( A.EMPLID=B.EMPLID AND A.EFFDT=B.EFFDT AND a.rn=b.rn)
```

I'm assuming here you're just interested in having side by side the info of the two tables linked by EMPLID and EFFDT, and that table1 and table2 will always have the same record number for the same key.

I've created an example for you to test at [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/PPUQ61243).

**Edited: new version**

I've tried to manage also the new "requirements" that have been submitted here as comments. 
It's getting complicated, but I hope that's what you need:

```
 SELECT a.EMPLID,a.DEDCD, to_char(a.EFFDT,'YYYY-MM-DD') EFFDT, b.DEDCD as DEDCD2,GTN
    FROM 
    (
    select  t1.EFFDT,t1.GTN,t1.EMPLID,t1.DEDCD,
         row_number() over (partition by t1.EMPLID order by case when t2.EMPLID is not null then 0 else 1 end asc, t1.DEDCD) rn
  from table1 t1 left join (select distinct EMPLID,   EFFDT, DEDCD from    table2) t2 on  t1.EMPLID=t2.EMPLID AND t1.EFFDT=t2.EFFDT  and t1.DEDCD=t2.DEDCD
        ) A
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     (
    select  t2.EFFDT,t2.EMPLID,t2.DEDCD,
         row_number() over (partition by t2.EMPLID order by case when t1.EMPLID is not null then 0 else 1 end asc, t2.DEDCD) rn
  from table2 t2  left join (select distinct EMPLID,   EFFDT, DEDCD from    table1) t1 on  t1.EMPLID=t2.EMPLID AND t1.EFFDT=t2.EFFDT and t1.DEDCD=t2.DEDCD
     ) B
  ON ( A.EMPLID=B.EMPLID AND A.EFFDT=B.EFFDT AND a.rn=b.rn)
```

I've created an example for you to test at [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/QYXZ77188)

Comment: However, if Table1 has 3 rows and Table2 has 2 , I am getting an undesired result. Can that we overcome ?

Comment: Also, if the DEDCD matches it should be shown in the same row.

Comment: @R_Prasad does the edited version satisfy your new requirements?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just have to figure out one issue. When the value of DEDCD matches it should be on the same row. Somehow, for some values DEDCDs does not match, even when the emplids have same DEDCDs in tables. For example, if an employee has XXYY & XXY1 in table 1 and XXYY & XXYZ , value matching XXYY should be in the same row. But it is not.

Comment: I tried to test your scenario on rextester(http://rextester.com/IKLWJ56409) but it's still working correctly, so I must have misunderstood. Could you please modify it,  fork it and post the resulting link,  so I can understand the issue you're facing?

Comment: Just to be sure..  You are using the 2nd query of my answer,  right?

Comment: Yes , I am using the second query.

Comment: My bad, I am now using the second query and it is working as desired. You sir are wonderful. Any good books/links I can read to get some more knowledge ?

Comment: It's been I while since I last read a book on Oracle.. I'm not the best person to ask this, On the links I've been an avid reader of AskTom (https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:1:0). I'd suggest you also to have a deep look into Analytical functions (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23sql-1906475.html) as they are very powerful.

Comment: please help, I have a modified requirement and I am unable to get the desired results

Comment: I'd suggest to open a new request and provide some sample data to explain what you would like to achieve from the query. It's unlikely that anyone would concentrate on a question that is tagged as "answered" on StackOverflow

Comment: Thanks @Insac, I have opened a new thread and added the condition. Kindly check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40852905/sql-join-with-when-data-matches

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by using simple join as below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.EMPLID, B.DEDCD AS DEDCD_2, A.EFFDT, A.DEDCD AS DEDCD_1
FROM table1 A
INNER JOIN table2 B ON A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID
    AND A.EFFDT = B.EFFDT
```

Comment: Does Oracle accept those square brackets for the delimited identifiers?

Comment: Simple join will give me more rows always. I am looking to limit the row to the number of rows in Table1. I tried "Right outer join" and "left outer join" but does not work

Comment: In the example,  all the EFFDT have the same value,  so this query wouldn't remove duplicates.

Comment: You can use DISTINCT to avoid duplicate rows.

Comment: My wrong: I said "duplicate" but they are simply "additional rows that we're still unclear why they shouldn't appear in the resultset". In the example DISTINCT wouldn't help,  as the four rows resulting would be different (and the OP just wants 2 of them)

Answer (score 0):

I used the following SQL to find the rows. Those who marked it incorrect question need to understand the question first. If I was unable to represent the question correctly, please tell me before voting it down.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DEDCD,EMPLID,DEDCD2 
 ,XX_GTN_nbr 
  FROM 
  (
  select  A.XX_GTN_nbr,A.EMPLID,A.DEDCD,B.DEDCD AS DEDCD2,
       row_number() over (partition by B.DEDCD
       order by A.EMPLID) rn
from PS_XX_PY50_GDED_RP A LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_GENL_DEDUCTION B
ON ( A.EMPLID=B.EMPLID AND A.EFFDT=B.EFFDT)
WHERE A.DEDCD<>' ' 
 ) WHERE RN=1;
```

Comment: Have you tested on the sample example you have attached to the question? Because it would seem to me that, when EMPLID is '1' for all the related rows, the `order by A.EMPLID` is not sufficient to guarantee you that the same rows is returned every time you execute the query.

Comment: Ok, I found another site where to test Oracle SQL (sqlfiddle seems to have troubles with it). You can see it [here](http://rextester.com/WNAUR82208). The issue I have with this query is that it just count on the "insertion order" of the rows in table1. This is rarely a good idea as some administration task (rebuilding of the table)  and application task (e.g. updates) can change the order, thus changing the result of your query. If GTN is a "global transaction number", I'd suggest you to use that as a sorting criteria to guarantee you that the query result stays the same.

Comment: By the way, I just realized that the query doesn't return your desired result: it returns    always XXYZ (or XXYY) for the EMPLID column